# ordenar filas en columnas en postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Tengo una tabla donde guardo seguimientos de evaluaciones nutricionales de personas, cada persona puede tener entre 1 a 6 evaluaciones y todas se almacenan es dicha tabla, lo que quiero hacer es que momento de descargar esta información me traiga los datos de la persona 1 vez pero el resultado de cada visita sea el que se agrega por ejemplo

```
nombre|apellido|telefono|fecha_evaluacion|resultado_evaluacion
pedro |perez   |5558877 | 05/05/2017     | desnutricion
pedro |perez   |5558877 | 05/07/2017     | adecuado
```

y necesito que me lo regrese de la siguiente forma

```
nombre|apellido|telefono|fecha_evaluacion1|resultado_evaluacion1|fecha_evaluacion2 | resultado_evaluacion2
pedro | perez  |5558877 |  05/05/2017     | desnutricion        | 05/07/2017       | Adecuado
```

cada persona puede tener hasta 6 evaluaciones y solo me interesa repetir la fecha de cada evaluacion y su diagnostico.

Comment: No está muy claro lo que preguntas: quieres que la consulta te devuelva los datos ordenados o es al mostrarlos al usuario?

Comment: es al consultar que me los regrese ordenados

Comment: no tienes mas datos en la tabla? seria ideal un id_persona o el número de la visita

Answer (score 0):

Su base de datos debería ser de dos entidades(tablas), una "personas" y otra "seguimientos." Al intentar mostrar dos columnas por cada seguimiento, tiene que tener en cuenta que usted debe definir las dos columnas, ya que SQL no puede crear columnas por si sola. Entonces si usted quiere mostrar los seis seguimientos, debe definir las demás columnas que quiere mostrar, en este caso serían 12 y la consulta básicamente sería la siguiente.

```
      SELECT p.nombre, p.apellido, p.telefono,
      (SELECT se.fecha_evaluacion FROM seguimientos se WHERE se.id_persona=p.id_persona LIMIT 0,1) AS fecha_evaluacion1,
      (SELECT se.resultado_evaluacion FROM seguimientos se WHERE se.id_persona=p.id_persona LIMIT 0,1) AS resultado_evaluacion1,
      (SELECT se.fecha_evaluacion FROM seguimientos se WHERE se.id_persona=p.id_persona LIMIT 1,1) AS fecha_evaluacion2,
      (SELECT se.resultado_evaluacion FROM seguimientos se WHERE se.id_persona=p.id_persona LIMIT 1,1) AS resultado_evaluacion2,
      (SELECT se.fecha_evaluacion FROM seguimientos se WHERE se.id_persona=p.id_persona LIMIT 2,1) AS fecha_evaluacion3,
      (SELECT se.resultado_evaluacion FROM seguimientos se WHERE se.id_persona=p.id_persona LIMIT 2,1) AS resultado_evaluacion3,
      (SELECT se.fecha_evaluacion FROM seguimientos se WHERE se.id_persona=p.id_persona LIMIT 3,1) AS fecha_evaluacion4,
      (SELECT se.resultado_evaluacion FROM seguimientos se WHERE se.id_persona=p.id_persona LIMIT 3,1) AS resultado_evaluacion4,
      (SELECT se.fecha_evaluacion FROM seguimientos se WHERE se.id_persona=p.id_persona LIMIT 4,1) AS fecha_evaluacion5,
      (SELECT se.resultado_evaluacion FROM seguimientos se WHERE se.id_persona=p.id_persona LIMIT 4,1) AS resultado_evaluacion5,
      (SELECT se.fecha_evaluacion FROM seguimientos se WHERE se.id_persona=p.id_persona LIMIT 5,1) AS fecha_evaluacion6,
      (SELECT se.resultado_evaluacion FROM seguimientos se WHERE se.id_persona=p.id_persona LIMIT 5,1) AS resultado_evaluacion6,
      FROM personas p INNER JOIN seguimientos s ON(p.id_persona=s.id_persona)
      GROUP BY p.nombre, p.apellido, p.telefono
```

Comment: me da un error Jonathan ch me dice una subconsulta utilizada como expresión retornó más de un registro que podria hacer en ese caso?

Comment: Ya modifiqué la respuesta, no tuve en cuenta limitar el numero de registros a obtener, que en este caso es uno por cada evaluación.
Creo que así ya serviría, aunque esa forma de `LIMIT` es para mysql, es decir que si utiliza otro gestor como posgresql o oracle, la sintaxis va a cambiar.

Comment: Gracias Jonathan ch asi lo hizo en el caso de postgres utilice el limit y el offset para indicar cada una de las posiciones, el problema es que con tantos registros que tengo en la tabla actualmente no ne da una respuesta son casi 120.000 mil registros

Comment: ¿Pero sí funcionó?
Pues si son muchos se va a demorar demasiado haciendo la consulta, entonces sería ponerle un limite como 30 a la consulta padre para ver que funcione.

Comment: si la consulta funciono perfectamente, el detalle es la cantidad pero para unos 50 registros trabaja perfectamente

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez puedas intentar algo como esto

```
select *
from crosstab (
    'select id, name, value
    from tt1
    order by 1,2')
AS (row_name int, col1 text, col2 text, col3 text, col4 text);
```

Donde puedes seleccionar los rows que deseas en forma de columnas

Answer (score 0):

Una forma posible es numerar cada evaluación de 1 a n (siendo n un número máximo fijo, según mencionas 6) y luego hacer un `GROUP BY` combinado con alguna función de agregación condicional. Te muestro un ejemplo en base a los datos que aportaste dónde solo tendrías dos juegos de columnas a transponer, pero no es difícil adaptarlo a una mayor cantidad:

Creamos en primer lugar los datos:

```
CREATE TABLE Ejemplo (
  nombre                  VARCHAR(255),
  apellido                VARCHAR(255),
  telefono                VARCHAR(255),
  fecha_evaluacion        DATE,
  resultado_evaluacion    VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO Ejemplo (nombre, apellido, telefono, fecha_evaluacion, resultado_evaluacion)
VALUES ('pedro','perez','5558877', '05/05/2017', 'desnutricion'),
       ('pedro','perez','5558877', '05/07/2017', 'adecuado');
```

Y aquí la consulta:

```
SELECT M.nombre, 
       M.apellido,
       MAX(CASE WHEN M.Nro = 1 THEN fecha_evaluacion ELSE NULL END)     AS Fecha1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN M.Nro = 1 THEN resultado_evaluacion ELSE NULL END) AS Resultado1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN M.Nro = 2 THEN fecha_evaluacion ELSE NULL END)     AS Fecha2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN M.Nro = 2 THEN resultado_evaluacion ELSE NULL END) AS Resultado2
       FROM ( SELECT nombre, 
                     apellido, 
                     fecha_evaluacion, 
                     resultado_evaluacion,
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY nombre, apellido ORDER BY fecha_evaluacion) AS Nro
                     FROM Ejemplo
       ) M
       GROUP BY M.nombre, 
                M.apellido;
```

La salida:

```
+--------+----------+------------+--------------+------------+------------+
| nombre | apellido | fecha1     | resultado1   | fecha2     | resultado2 |
+--------+----------+------------+--------------+------------+------------+
| pedro  | perez    | 2017-05-05 | desnutricion | 2017-05-07 | adecuado   |
+--------+----------+------------+--------------+------------+------------+
```